# Speed effects of parentheses for indexing and functions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, syntax, overloading

I was recently told by some developers that the way MATLAB uses parentheses to denote array indexing **and** functions (e.g., array(1:10) and max(vals)) results in a sacrifice of speed because the program has to determine how they are being used. Is this true? If so, why would Mathworks not differentiate with square brackets similar to Python?

Comment: (a) Because they can't change the syntax once they have it.  (b) The parsing time will generally be negligible compared to actual execution time.

Comment: To add to @OliCharlesworth's point, once a file is parsed (run once) it will remain in memory until the function is cleared or the M-File is edited (or possibly if cleared if more RAM is needed, but I'm not sure if this ever happens).

Comment: Additionally, the overall implementation quality of the parser is likely to the bigger factor rather than one aspect of a language. Let me guess, these developers were Python developers who've had to port a lot of Matlab code?

Comment: Actually, a CS professor whose students developed Julia. He claimed that was one of the reasons MATLAB was so slow, but I was very skeptical.

Comment: To add to @OliCharlesworth, MATLAB was [initially](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/the-origins-of-matlab.html) (search for `first version of MATLAB`) designed to allow students to work with the Fortran libraries LINPACK and EISPACK.  Some of the original syntax was likely inspired by Fortran which also uses `()` for calls and indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was already mentioned in the comments, but here is a summary including additions:

1. It doesn't matter much (that is the only real important reason I suppose)
2. Historically they chose these brackets
3. Square brackets (or curly brackets) already have different uses in MATLAB